# {{ entry.image.first().url }} won't show image

Tags: templating, image

I am on my first Craft CMS test site. Have some problems showing a simple image.

```
<img src="{{ entry.hero.first().url }}" title="{{ hero.title }}">
```

I get the title but can't get the URL. The src attr is always empty. Tried a couple of variants like:

- `entry.hero.first().url()`
- `entry.hero.first().getUrl()`
- with and without ()
- etc.

But `entry.hero.first().filename` gives me "my_testfile01.jpg"

I can't see what is wrong.

File is local with path set to "./"
Image field has no sub path.

MAMP (Apache + PHP 7)

Answer (score 2):

By the way, is your Craft CMS version 3.x? If so, using "one" is recommended instead of "first", which is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Nothing seems to work to get the file path

Answer (score 1):

Is the "Assets in this volume have public URLs" turned on?

Comment: It wasn't before. But I found it a little later and turned it on. Still frontend won't show the image nor an error. Noticed thumbnails in CP show, but if I click to preview it, the image is 404.

Comment: Maybe you defined wrong path in volume - what is there? What is the path that errors out 404?

Comment: I guess not, because getting the filename works. There must be something wrong with the output

Comment: What have you set as base URL for the volume?